# Deleting a file from documents directory when going back in UINavigation

Tags: objective-c, file

I'm trying to delete a file in my Documents directory when the user presses back in a view with UINavigation. When I run my code go back then go back to the view, I get the following error and the app crashes:

> 2014-07-28 18:19:42.446 App[13291:a0b] nested pop animation can result
>   in corrupted navigation bar
>
> 2014-07-28 18:19:42.798 App[13291:a0b] Finishing up a navigation
>   transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might
>   get corrupted.

**My Code**

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    if ([self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self]==NSNotFound) {
        // Navigation button was pressed. Do some stuff
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:_url ofType:@"plist"];
        NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *temp = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[dict objectForKey:@"FolderName"]];
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath: temp error:nil];

        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

Comment: I guess when this view controller appears an object in created. Maybe you should show it modally and delete the object upon dismissal of the modal view.
To your Code: why `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];`? Isn't the view controller already popped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the back button has been pressed, the navigation controller is already in the process of popping the current view controller. Try it without the call to popViewControllerAnimated:

If you need to perform certain actions related to pushing/popping view controllers, you can also look into the UINavigationControllerDelegate methods.